# How to update DataGridView using ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net, combobox

```
private void tbComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
 this.mytbTableAdapter.Fill(this.dbDataSet.mytb);
          }
```

Updating is only if to select the line a second time. And if moving and click on the rows,  the update will fall behind on a one row (the update  for the previous row, not selected)...

Comment: Please be more clear about your problem you are facing because I can't figure out what are you trying to tell. How are you showing the data in the DataGridView? Are you using a BindingSource or the dbDataSet.mytb directly?

Comment: DataGridView, ComboBox and theirs BindingSource, TableAdapters created automatically by dragging and dropping onto a Form from Data Source.